# Flutter - customised ThemeData not working properly

Tags: flutter, fonts

I have created the following theme for my app:

```
class MyPortfolio extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final myPortfolio = "my portfolio";

return MaterialApp(
  title: myPortfolio,
  theme: ThemeData(
    primaryColor: Color.fromRGBO(10, 16, 19, 100),
    //  accentColor:,
    fontFamily: 'Futura',
    textTheme: TextTheme(
      headline5: TextStyle(fontSize: 13),
  ),
  home: MyAppBar(),
);}}
```

I have then applied it to my app as followed:

```
class _MyAppBarState extends State<MyAppBar> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      elevation: 0.0,
      title: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Logo(),
          // action button
          FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _select(choices[0]);
              },
              child: Text(
                'Portfolio',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5,
              )),...
```

My pubspec.yaml as below:

```
flutter:
 fonts:
  - family: Baskerville
    fonts:
      - asset: fonts/Baskerville.ttc
  - family: Futura
    fonts:
      - asset: fonts/Futura.ttc
  - family: Tinos
    fonts:
      - asset: fonts/Tinos-Italic.ttf
        style: italic
      - asset: fonts/Tinos-BoldItalic.ttf
        weight: 700
 uses-material-design: true
```

However, when I try to access the font here, it is showing the default headline5 font style rather than my customised one. 
May I ask if anyone has any advice please?

Comment: could you please share your pubspec.yaml code where you're importing the font

Comment: @CubeRootX I have just shared my pubspec.yaml. The fonts actually worked before I customise my app with ThemeData..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem has been solved as I have been stupidly using MaterialApps in other parts of my app as well, hence the ThemeData couldn't function properly.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a new instance of MaterialApp widget in your _MyAppBarState it is using default parameters.

```
class MyPortfolio extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final myPortfolio = "my portfolio";

return MaterialApp(
debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  title: myPortfolio,
  theme: ThemeData(
    primaryColor: Color.fromRGBO(10, 16, 19, 100),
    //  accentColor:,
    fontFamily: 'Futura',
    textTheme: TextTheme(
      headline5: TextStyle(fontSize: 13),
  ),
  home: MyAppBar(),
);}}

class _MyAppBarState extends State<MyAppBar> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      elevation: 0.0,
      title: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Logo(),
          // action button
          FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _select(choices[0]);
              },
              child: Text(
                'Portfolio',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5,
              )),...
```

Comment: Hi I have tried the above, with an error displayed :"The following assertion was thrown building MyAppBar(state: _MyAppBarState#9531a):
MediaQuery.of() called with a context that does not contain a MediaQuery.
No MediaQuery ancestor could be found starting from the context that was passed to MediaQuery.of().
This can happen because you do not have a WidgetsApp or MaterialApp widget (those widgets introduce
a MediaQuery), or it can happen if the context you use comes from a widget above those widgets.
The context used was:
  Scaffold
The relevant error-causing widget was:
  MyAppBar "